# Null message body

Tags: shell, oozie-workflow

echo test=$( "Message Body " | mail -s "Subject Testing " -a $(ls -dt $PWD/*|head -1) abc@def.com)

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: I want to use $test variable later in my workflow. By using the above cmd I am getting an email with attachment but null body. How can I get the Message Body printed?

Comment: I want to attach the first file in the current working directory to an email alert action in an oozie workflow. I tried using "<attachment>${wf:actionData('email_body')['latest_file']}</attachment>" where latest_file is the path to the file but did not worked. So I tried sending email through shell script using above command. Even this is not printing the message body.

Comment: You want `echo "Message Body" | mail ...` or `<<<"Message Body" mail ...` -- there's no command named just `"Message Body"`, so it isn't a thing you can pipe from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I get you right. You want to mail with an attachment and a body, and set $test variable the message? Why don't just set it explicitly.

Or you just wanna know how to add the message body to the mail? If so, it would be like this.

```bash
mail -A hello.txt -s "Subject Test" abc@def.com <<< "This is the message"
```

Use -A for debian based systems, which uses mailutils package.

Comment: can you please explain what does this hello.txt does? and I am unable to give full email body, in the place of " This is the message" only single line of message is accepting.

Comment: Oh, that is just a example file in your case use `$(ls -dt $PWD/*|head -1)` instead.

Comment: And if you want to send with multiple line you can save that into a text file and use `mail -A hello.txt -s "Subject Test" abc@def.com < message.txt `